# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS: UEFI install. Resized GPT partition and now can't boot

Tags: resize, gdisk

Before I did the resize, I had 3 partitions:

```
root@panda1:/mnt1# gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 60062500 sectors, 28.6 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B35654BD-05BF-422D-9C13-FA11F69BAFC6
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 60062466
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2785 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624        26734591   12.2 GiB    8300
   3        26734592        60061695   15.9 GiB    8200

Command (? for help): i
```

- partition #1 = EFI System Partition
- partition #2 = the root / filesystem
- partition #3 = swap partition

I first deleted partitions #2, and #3 with the 'd' command.
Then recreated partition #2 with the 'n' command, specifying the same start sector as before, and new end sector at the end of the disk.  Essentially, I am deleting the swap partition and using that space to extend the / filesystem.

I also used the 'x' command to enter expert mode, then 'c' to change the partition GUID back to what it was before.  This was needed because creating the partition #2 again assigned it a new GUID.  gdisk also gave the partition the name 'Linux filesystem' but I renamed it back to '' (blank).

At the end it looked like this:

```
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 60062500 sectors, 28.6 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): B35654BD-05BF-422D-9C13-FA11F69BAFC6
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 60062466
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624        60062466   28.1 GiB    8300

Command (? for help): i
```

After this, I then did 'e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2' and 'resize2fs /dev/sdb2'.  All of which went fine.  I can mount the filesystem and verify everything works.

Note that I did this on a second PC with the first PC's boot drive mounted as /dev/sdb.  Then I moved the hard drive back to the first PC.

Problem is: After this is done, it won't boot!  PC just shows a black screen.  No response to keyboard.